# How to simulate CTRL+Click with watir-webdriver?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I want to simulate ctrl keydown and ctrl keyup.

My use-case is the following:

The user can select from a list (build with a table) multiple elements by pressing CTRL key and clicking on the desired row. When the CTRL key is released an AJAX call will be made.

I need a watir test to simulate this. How can i do this ? Any ideas ?
I would need a solution that works under Linux

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did the answer work out for you?  if yes then you should have the courtesy to 'accept' the answer so that the person who helped you gets credit for a correct answer

Answer (score 5):

I believe the best way to send comands would be to do the following:

`require 'watir-webdriver'`

`browser.send_keys[:control].send_keys[: arrow_up]`
`browser.send_keys[:control].send_keys[: arrow_down]`

If you want to check out some more key options here is a link:

[Link to other key stroke options](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.rb?r=14170)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was a good answer at the time the question was asked, but there is now a better way, See @Lloyd's answer below

Answer (score 5):

Realising this is old, but the original question didn't quite get answered, the way I have completed this is to do:

```
browser.a.click(:control)
```

If you are on a mac system you may want to use **:command**.

See http://watir.com/guides/special-keys/

Comment: That would be the correct CURRENT best answer to this.  When the question was asked we didn't have that capability.  It's something I and others asked for and was added a few months back.

Answer (score 2):

After some playing around with Ruby 1.9.2 and the Watir Webdriver I found this worked for sending multiple keys to the browser simultaneously:

```
browser.send_keys [:alt, :arrow_left]
```

OS: Win64
Browser: Firefox