# send_keys in watir webdriver with firefox

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and watir webdriver 0.6.4 with firefox 22. 
I want select two rows in a table at a time  but send_keys(:control) is not working. 
I have tried all of the solutions provided in the following link but they are not working
[Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858699/how-to-simulate-ctrlclick-with-watir-webdriver)

Hers is my code snippet:

method 1:

```
while (element > 0)
 element -= 1
 $browser.send_keys :control
 $browser.table(:id => "proposedConfigs").tr(:id ,"proposedConfigs__#{element}").click
end
```

method 2:

```
while (element > 0)
 element -= 1
 $browser.send_keys [:control,:arrow_down]
 $browser.table(:id => "proposedConfigs").tr(:id ,"proposedConfigs__#{element}").click
 $browser.send_keys [:control, :arrow_up]
end
```

method 3:

```
$browser.send_keys :control (or)  $browser.element.send_keys :control 
$browser.table(:id => "proposedConfigs").tr(:id ,"proposedConfigs__0").click
$browser.table(:id => "proposedConfigs").tr(:id ,"proposedConfigs__1").click
```

Result :  selecting only one element for all the above

method 4:

```
$browser.table(:id => "proposedConfigs").tr(:id ,"proposedConfigs__#  {element}").click(:control)
```

result:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native interaction:
Could not load native event's component.
```

But with firefox 22 the native events are already disabled.

When i tried to

```
$browser.send_keys [:control,:key_down]
$browser.send_keys [:control,:press_down]
```

result :

```
these methods are not available
```

When I tried:

```
$browser.send_keys[:control].send_keys[:arrow_up]
```

result:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `send_keys' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: show your code... and also the evidence(if any error) to show us that the code of your is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate CTRL+Click with watir-webdriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858699/how-to-simulate-ctrlclick-with-watir-webdriver)

Comment: I already tried the sol in that question but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I cannot reproduce your results. On my system, this works well:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
h = Headless.new
h.start
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'http://www.google.com'
b.span(:id => 'gbqfsa').click(:control) # => []
```

Note that the way I sent the 'control' signal above is [the canonical way](http://watirwebdriver.com/sending-special-keys/) of sending a key  *with* a click as far as I can tell. My best guess is that sending the key on its own means that the key is released immediately. So `b.element.send_keys [:control]` would be meaningless unless your table row responds to just pushing the same key on the keyboard ... which would be a weird table. Just a guess though.

My system:

- ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]
- watir-webdriver (0.6.8)
- headless (1.0.1)
- Mozilla Firefox 24.2.0
- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

If you have control over your system, consider upgrading Ruby, Firefox and your gems. There is [some evidence to support the idea that updates have broken backward compatibility here](http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/hover-mouse-over-does-not-work-with-firefox-18-with-latest-selenium-webdriver-2-27-2-td18664.html), albeit with different versions.